Jetty 12 with Scala "Unable to locate class corresponding to inner class entry for Scope"
After upgrading jetty-server from 11 to 12, the compilation (using mill as the build tool) fails with:
Unable to locate class corresponding to inner class entry for Scope in owner org.eclipse.jetty.server.UserIdentity

But nowhere in my servlet code this UserIdentity class is used.
What might this error message mean and how to fix it?
My full list of dependencies (with versions that still worked):
  def ivyDeps = Agg( // https://search.maven.org
    ivy"org.apache.kafka::kafka-streams-scala::2.8.2",
    ivy"org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:11.0.2",
    ivy"org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-jetty-server:11.0.22",
    ivy"org.json4s::json4s-jackson::4.0.7",
    ivy"org.scala-lang.modules::scala-parallel-collections::1.0.4",
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.13",
    ivy"org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.13",
    ivy"com.github.scopt::scopt::4.1.0"
  )


Any chance you have multiple versions of Jetty being pulled transitively by different dependencies?

As @GaëlJ asked, is it possible you are having version conflicts? Could you edit your post and shows the list of dependencies and versions you have? Not in the comments, in the post to make it more readable and let other people understand better your issue

@GastónSchabas I added the list of dependencies in the build.sc

jetty guide from 11 to 12, says replace org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-jetty-server with org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:jetty-websocket-jetty-server 12. Instead of using org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-jetty-server:11.0.22, you should use org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:jetty-websocket-jetty-server:12.0.11

Not sure if zinc - Unable to locate class file for inner class could be related with the problem you are having. zinc is the incremental compiler used by build tools such as mill, sbt, gradle and some other ones. Have you tried to do a fresh run? Maybe with mill clean and then mill run?

I haven't used jetty. So, I don't know how to create a hello world from scala. If my comments above are not enough, feel free to edit your post and provide a minimal reproducible example.
